Exporting exr/png sequence from Davinci resolve into Blender as Image plane looks flat
I want to colour match Blender render in Cycles with a image sequence exported from Davinci resolve. Here is my input and output colour space transform from Davinci resolve.
Input Colour Space: Sony S-Gamut3.Cine
Input Gamma: Sony S-log3
Output Colour Space: Rec.709
Output Gamma: sRGB
When exporting both PNG and EXR sequence into the 3D layer as image plane, the colour is completely off in viewport and rendered image. Which settings would correctly match in this scenario please?

EXR doesnt have a color space. So dont expect a match between PNG and EXR. If your PNGs are Rec.709, then with a colormanagment set to Standard, you should get the result you want.

Thanks. I was still getting a flat image with PNG sequence until I imported with shadeless in material settings for importing image as plane. by default it was set to Principled.
